# How Port Linux onto MAIXDUINO board with Kendryte K210 core?

Tags: linux, riscv, soc

I am trying to port Linux OS onto the maixduino board as RISC-V resources say that Linux can be ported onto the Kendryte K210 core. I am using the binary file from https://dl.sipeed.com/MAIX/MaixLinux/Firmware and using kflash in the terminal of my Ubuntu machine to try flash it onto the board using the command
kflash -p /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200 -B maixduino Maix-linux-5.6-rc1.bin

Afterwhich I get ‘FileNotFoundError’ not defined line:
[INFO] COM Port Selected Manually: /dev/ttyUSB0
[INFO] Default baudrate is 115200 , later it may be changed to the value you set.
global name ‘FileNotFoundError’ is not defined

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Should this now be easier in the meanwhile, as this got merged to the linux kernel? Any updates on progress?

Answer (score -1):

$ sudo pip3 install kflash

you must add yourself to dialout group as follows or you have to use sudo every time
$ sudo usermod -a -G dialout $(whoami)

You can try Kflash GUI:
use the below Kflash gui tool as mentioned below where you can manually change board settings and serial settings

https://github.com/sipeed/kflash_gui

Make sure that hardware connections are proper and try with low baud rate, check the USB device name usually represented by ttyUSB*